# Unit test for uploading a png file

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am a beginner in unit tests and I want to test my typescript method **onSelect** that allow user to select only image, pdf and word files. This is my typescript method :

```
 addedfiles : Array<any> = [];
 fileRestrictions: FileRestrictions = {
  allowedExtensions: ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg', '.doc', '.docx','.pdf'],
   maxFileSize: 5000000
  };
public onSelect(ev: any): void {
  ev.files.forEach((file: FileInfo) => {
 
  if (file.rawFile) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if(this.fileRestrictions.allowedExtensions.includes(file.extension.toLowerCase()))
    {reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.addedfiles.push({ ...file, src: reader.result as string });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
    console.log(this.addedfiles)
    }
    }
   });
   }
```

I want to write a unit test that test if this method allow users to select png files. So I create this unit test :

```
it('should select a png file', () => {

  const ev = { prevented : false , files : [{uid : '01', name : 'filename', extension : 'png' 
  , size : 123000 }]};

  component.onSelect(ev);

  expect(component.addedfiles.length).toEqual(1);
```

} )

It gives me the Error : `Expected 0 to equal 1` !  Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Hi, I see that there is a check for `file.rawFile`. And in unit test you don't have that set. Try this for ev?
    `const ev = { prevented : false, files : [{uid : '01', name : 'filename', extension : 'png', size : 123000, rawFile: true }]};` Or a more appropriate value for rawFile :)

Comment: @user3009269 no it still the same problem , PS : when I console.log(addedfiles) in my onSelect method and select a png file it works fine and the addefiles is not empty ! So probably the unit test is not correct

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `FileReader` but maybe this would make more sense in your unit test as mock value for `rawFile`: `data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4`.

Comment: Hmmm... I think the problem is actually the fact that the file is added in addedFile in the async method `onloadend`... So your unit test is hitting the expect function BEFORE the `onloadend` callback is executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `reader.onloadend = () => {...}` is a private function, so it's untestable.
You'd better use `reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {...})`. So we can mock `addEventListener` method.

Besides, [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is an exact match, your test data `extension: 'png'` should be `extension: '.png'`. And, your test data misses `rawFile` property.

A working example using `angular` v11+:

`example.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

type FileRestrictions = any;
type FileInfo = any;

@Component({})
export class ExampleComponent {
  addedfiles: Array<any> = [];
  fileRestrictions: FileRestrictions = {
    allowedExtensions: ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg', '.doc', '.docx', '.pdf'],
    maxFileSize: 5000000,
  };
  public onSelect(ev: any): void {
    ev.files.forEach((file: FileInfo) => {
      if (file.rawFile) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        if (
          this.fileRestrictions.allowedExtensions.includes(
            file.extension.toLowerCase()
          )
        ) {
          console.log(reader);
          reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
            this.addedfiles.push({ ...file, src: reader.result as string });
          });
          reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
          console.log(this.addedfiles);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`example.component.spec.ts`:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ExampleComponent } from './example.component';

fdescribe('65356063', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;
  let component: ExampleComponent;
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ExampleComponent],
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExampleComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    })
  );

  it('should select a png file', () => {
    const ev = {
      prevented: false,
      files: [
        {
          uid: '01',
          name: 'filename',
          extension: '.png',
          size: 123000,
          rawFile: 'test raw file',
        },
      ],
    };

    const mockReader = {
      addEventListener: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake((event, listener) => {
        listener();
      }),
      readAsDataURL: jasmine.createSpy(),
    };
    spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(
      (mockReader as unknown) as FileReader
    );

    component.onSelect(ev);

    expect(component.addedfiles.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(mockReader.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith(
      'loadend',
      jasmine.any(Function)
    );
    expect(mockReader.readAsDataURL).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('test raw file');
  });
});
```

test result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 thanks for answering ! I have a compiling error `Property 'toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith' does not exist on type 'Matchers<any>'.`

Comment: @hibanebli You can use `toHaveBeenCalled()` as well

Comment: it gives me this error `error TS2345: Argument of type '"FileReader"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "status" | "location" | "top" | "Blob" | "URL" | "URLSearchParams" | "applicationCache" | "caches" | "clientInformation" | "closed" | "crypto" | "customElements" | "defaultStatus" | ... 221 more ... | "onunload"'.

81     spyOn(window, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(`

Comment: @hibanebli You can cast the type of the return value to `any`

Comment: Thank you so much it works with success now